# Partial derivative of an ordinary derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am working on some research project involving partial differential equations with respect to the variable $u(x,t)$ and I am stuck with this expression:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\mbox{d}x}{\mbox{d}t}\cdot u(x,t)\right),$$

where $x=x(t)$.

Is there something wrong with this expression; or is expression just the following?

$$\frac{\mbox{d}x}{\mbox{d}t}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the reason why there are two notations for the derivative in the expression, is that the "d" stands for the Total Derivative. You should try looking that up.

Comment: You can go from first principles, consider the definitions of the ordinary and partial derivatives

Comment: On the other hand, this could depend on the context. If this expression comes from a physics problem, please specify what all the parameters mean and where does this expression appear?

Comment: Your answer is right. $\frac{{d}x}{{d}t}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Comment: When I had a course on calculus of variations, many of my mates used to struggle with such things. So what they did is that they used to call total derivatives like $\frac{dx}{dt}$ by some other variable e.g. $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Still don't know why, but it helped them.

Comment: @YuriyS this is from a physics problem, where I am trying to find the Fokker Planck equation for a continuous stochastic process. Here $u$ is the PDF of the continuous stochastic process, which is why the term $\frac{dx}{dt}$ exists.